# PHP database connection error to local host

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$db="project";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$conn=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die("Mysql is not Connected");

mysql_select_db($db,$conn) or die("DB is not Connected");
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);
?>
```

> Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in
>   E:\Programs\wamp64\www\ayar.php on line 6

it is a error about connecting to data base this project worked in 2014 but it is not working now.

Comment: Which php version you are using? `mysql_*` lib has been removed from PHP v7. please switch to PDO or mysqli.

Comment: please migrate to mysqli_ or any more modern connectors. mysql_ has many security flaws and it is not maintained anymore

Comment: wampserver3.1.4_x64 

i installed it.

Comment: Should i change my all query to mysqli or PDO ? there are a lot of codes :/

Comment: Yes you should, I know it's pain in the a** but at some point in the future, you have to do it anyway.

Comment: ohh too much work for me anyway i should do it thank you for all.

Comment: Please keep in mind for your next posts to first spent some time searching on the web. In google, the first hit for mysql_connect gives the information you needed to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

First check your PHP version first if it's greater 5.5 then the above code won't work. Since PHP 5.5 has removed support for MySQL extension in favour of mysqli. So you need to do some changes into your code i.e shown below:

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$db="project";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die("Mysql is not Connected");

mysqli_select_db($conn,$db) or die("DB is not Connected");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can install earlier version of wampserver on which you can run php v=<5.5